# Eclipse: Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, android-sdk-tools

I tried to set up a new eclipse installation including the android sdk and adt plugin.
The installation of all parts complete without errors.
After setting the sdk path withing eclipse this error showed up:

`Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK.
The Android Developer Toolkit may not work properly.`

This shows up every time I start eclipse.
I didn't found a solution yet for fixing this error and I don't yet have a clue where this error comes from.

Further system information:

OS: Xubuntu 14.04
Eclipse Helios
Android SDK Tools: Rev. 23.0.2
Android SDK Build Tools: Rev. 20

Answer (score 1):

remove the existing adt plugin and re-install it. Please follow these instructions [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: I'm getting this on a brand-spanking-new, from-scratch Neon install with no ADT listed anywhere in the installed software