# Android SDK not opeing in Eclipse after update

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

> Yesterday i updated my android SDK manager. while update it shows some waring but i haven't red that. after completing the update . i opened Eclipse that time it displays the Error like below image.
>
> i tried in net i cant find the solution can any one tell me to solve this problem. 
>   [image: Error on my Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question , Is the error: Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK.The Android Developer Toolkit may not work properly. 
The picture is quite blurry,

Anyway here is the question with the answer [Eclipse: Failed to get the required ADT version number from the SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230176/eclipse-failed-to-get-the-required-adt-version-number-from-the-sdk)